# Gitlab CI tests fail

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, gitlab

I've created a batch script which run tests automatically (have a bin folder including all tests and dll's)
The whole software builds without problems on the CI.
the Tests run locally without errors (running the batch from my machine).

But if I run the tests with the gitlab runner on the CI-Server some tests fail.

Where is the difference? I'm new to die GitLab CI and don't understand the difference right now.

I am working with windows 7 :)

I'm happy with every suggestion.

Wish you a nice weekend :)

Comment: Could be any number of things. For example, one possible cause is that your tests require a file which is present on your machine but not in the CI environment. Posting your failing tests may help in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I create a batch script on the server with the same entries as my gitlab-ci yml file. No problems. Every file is present. 
Are there performance differences between local execution and execution with the runner?

Comment: There certainly could be. Are the failing tests related to performance?

Comment: Thats a good question :D
But I don't think so... 
If it's is related to perforamance the difference will be greater than a factor of ten!
I have no idea anymore ...

Comment: Have you set up the gitlab-runner as the user account on windows? (so it has the same access as the user you tested with which worked)

Comment: The permission are not the problem. I'm trying to debug this right now. 
Praying to god :D